# Remove computer from local network

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have local network with multiple computers connected.
Today I changed one of computer's name into more readable one, but unfortunately it was duplicated.

How can I remove invalid from the network's list?

On left is old invalid, on right new one:
[image: On left is old invalid, on right new one]

Comment: It takes time to update. You don't need to remove it, in time it will happen.

Comment: I've already tried flushing dns with reboot. Couldn't find more options to try on web.

Comment: It just disappeared. Could you write answer, so I could accept it ? Or should I answer myself?

Comment: You can answer it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, in my case system removed it automatically. But it took some time (more than hour for me).

[I also tried flushing DNS in that time period](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/delete-old-computer-name-from-network/b4d185bc-1d0a-408f-b464-34f8f203058e)

So I'm not sure if DNS flushing had any impact.